# SQL index optimization for high-volume inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to design a table for a very high number of inserts (basically telemetry data) that keeps the most recent records at the top of the table. This is because I want to make the queries, which will always want the most recent x number of records, to not have to perform any sorts or other heavy operations.

To accomplish this, I sorted the EventDate in the PK DESC because I assumed that would make the physical order of the table keep the highest date at the top.

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [FooId]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [EventDate]       INT NOT NULL,
    [Created]         DATETIME2 (7) DEFAULT GETUTCDATE() NOT NULL,
    [Updated]         DATETIME2 (7) NULL,
    [ResourceTypeId]  TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [ItemTypeId]      TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [ItemCount]       BIGINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    [ItemSize]        BIGINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EventDate] DESC, [ResourceTypeId] ASC, [ItemTypeId] ASC, [FooId] ASC)
)
```

In experimenting with different queries, I found something very strange. For example, this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.MyTable 
WHERE FooId = '9444D256-F304-4F1B-9624-F99C0E6988A6' AND EventDate + 300 >= 20221010
```

seems to perform *fewer* operations than this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE FooId = '9444D256-F304-4F1B-9624-F99C0E6988A6' AND EventDate >= 20220710
```

The first query:

| Operation | Est. Cost % | Est. CPU Cost | Est. IO Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Clustered Index Scan | 100 | 0.0001581 | 0.003125 |

The second query:

| Operation | Est. Cost % | Est. CPU Cost | Est. IO Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Clustered Index Seek | 100 | 0.0001581 | 0.003125 |
| Nested Loops | 0 | 0.0001581 | 0.003125 |
| Compute Scalar | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Constant Scan | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I know the seek is better, but is it worth the other operations? Is there a better way to design this table/queries?

Comment: Question, how can an EventDate of SMALLINT grow to be this large ->EventDate + 300 >= 20221010?

Comment: The first query scans the table due to the unsargable predicate. Why do you think inserting rows at the "top" is better? If you want the highest insert performance possible, use a heap table; otherwise a simple unique clustered index would be best, always insert rows at the end of the table.

Comment: Counting the number of operators in the plan is absolutely not how you should go about query tuning

Comment: You're listing estimated costs. How do those queries actually perform?

Comment: @RossBush ah, that was a mistake in modifying the data for the question. It is an INT. I'll update it.

Comment: @Stu I was thinking that inserting at the top would be better if I wanted to get the most recent 100 records, for instance, so SQL wouldn't have to sort the results. That may have been a totally incorrect assumption, it sounds like.

Comment: @BenThul Alas, I am still in the design phase, so I don't have actuals yet.

Comment: @joelforsyth With an index, SQL Server can follow it in both directions equally efficiently. What's easier, adding a block to the top of a Jenga tower or the bottom? Hint - the end of the table is like the top of the tower. It's not always that black and white but you get the idea.

Comment: Also consider the columns in your index - you are clustering on a Date column, this is an ever-increasing value; exactly how beneficial do you think adding additional columns are going to be, given each date value is [probably] unique? Each column in a clustered index is also part of every non-clustered index, that includes your guid.

Comment: There really is no concept of top vs bottom of a table.  If you don't have a clustered index - then each new row inserted will be inserted into the next space available on the current page.  Once that page is filled a new page is allocated and the next row is inserted on the new page.  For a clustered index - it depends on the column(s) used and expecting the INT column you have defined as a date will not guarantee an insert in the manner you believe.  If you want to ensure inserting in a similar manner as a heap - then you would want to define EventDate as a DATETIME2(7).

Comment: Or - you can use a sequential guid or identity.    But - none of those will guarantee that the rows are inserted in any particular order unless you can guarantee that each operation has been serialized and that one and only 1 row is inserted at a time.

Comment: @Stu the reason I included the other columns was for a MERGE statement that would always include them in the hopes of gaining performance. You've given me a lot to go on, so thank you very much!

Comment: @joelforsyth That would make sense if it were a non-clustered index, however this is the *clustered* index, ie, the leaf level *is* the table, and you're not *including* the columns (because of course you can't and that only makes sense for a non-clustered index).